# Calculated property for model EF Core - Property or Method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am new to EF core. I have a Customer model with the usual properties (Name,Address,Email).

I need a property to calculate the current balance for the customer.

This will be quite an intensive computation (once many records are stored) so am I correct in thinking that it should be stored in a Method, rather than a calculated property?

I am assuming I need to add a method such as .GetCurrentBalance().

Where would I put this method?

Simplified code below:

My Customer Model

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<SalesInvoice> SalesInvoices{ get; set; }
}
```

My Sales Invoice Model

```
public class SalesInvoice
{
    public int SalesInvoiceId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<SalesInvoiceDetail> SalesInvoiceDetails{ get; set; }
}
```

My Sales Invoice Detail Model

```
public class SalesInvoiceDetail
{
    public int SalesInvoiceDetailId { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm almost certain it could be calculated at the property level. It would be helpful if you share the customer model, at least the one you have at the moment.

Comment: It is an extremely simple model at the moment but to calculate the current balance, I would need to go through invoices, payments and credit notes. It would be quite intensive.

Comment: Don't put that in the model. Create LINQ query which returns IQueryable with calculated property. Then you can reuse this method in other places. If you put some code examples and how do you plan to use that, I'll give you advise.

Comment: I have updated my question, Svyatoslav Danyliv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper methods which returns desired results. Everything should play around IQueryable:

```cs
public class CustomerIdWithBalance
{
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerWithBalance
{
   public Customer Customer { get; set; }
   public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}

public static class BusinessLogicExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<CustomerIdWithBalance> GetCustomerIdAndBalance(this IQueryable<Customer> customers)
    {
        var grouped = 
           from c in customers
           from si in c.SalesInvoices
           from sid in si.SalesInvoiceDetails
           group sid by new { c.CustomerId } into g
           select new CustomerIdWithBalance
           {
               g.Key.CustomerId,
               Balance = x.Sum(x => x.Qty * x.UnitPrice)
           } 
        return grouped;
    }

    public static IQueryable<CustomerWithBalance> GetCustomerAndBalance(this IQueryable<CustomerIdWithBalance> customerBalances, IQueryable<Customer> customers)
    {
        var query =
           from b in customerBalances
           join c in customers on b.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
           select new CustomerWithBalance
           {
              Customer = c,
              Balance = b.Balance
           };
        return query;
    }

}
```

Later when you need to return that with API call (hypothetic samples)

```cs
var qustomerIdsWithHighBalance = 
   from c in ctx.Customers.GetCustomerIdAndBalance()
   where c.Balance > 1000
   select c.CustomerId;
```

```cs
var qustomersWithHighBalance = 
   ctx.Customers.GetCustomerIdAndBalance()
   .Where(c => c.Balance > 1000)
   .GetCustomerAndBalance(ctx.Customers);
```

```cs
var customersByMatchAndPagination = ctx.Customers
    .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("John"))
    .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
    .Skip(100)
    .Take(50)
    .GetCustomerAndBalance(ctx.Customers);
```

You will get desired results without additional database roundtrips. With properties you may load too much data into the memory.

It is everything about using EF with its limitations. But world is not stopped because EF team is too busy to create performance effective things.

Let's install https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq

And create extension methods around `Customer`

```cs
public static class CustomerExtensions
{
   [InjectLambda]
   public static TotalBalance(this Customer customer)
      => throw new NotImplmentedException();
  
   static Expression<Func<Customer, decimal>> TotalBalance()
   {
       return customer => 
           (from si in customer.SalesInvoices
            from sid in si.SalesInvoiceDetails
            select sid)
           .Sum(x => x.Qty * x.UnitPrice));
   }
}
```

And everything become handy:

```cs
var customersWithHighBalance = 
   from c in ctx.Customers.ToInjectable()
   where c.TotalBalance() > 1000
   select c;
```

```cs
var customersWithHighBalance = 
   from c in ctx.Customers.ToInjectable()
   let balance = c.TotalBalance()
   where balance = balance > 1000
   select new CustomerWithBalance
   {
       Customer = c,
       Balance = balance
   };
```

```cs
var customersWithBalance = 
   from c in ctx.Customers.ToInjectable()
   where c.Name.StartsWith("John")
   select new CustomerWithBalance
   {
       Customer = c,
       Balance = c.TotalBalance()
   };

var paginated = 
    .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
    .Skip(100)
    .Take(50);
```

Comment: Thank you, Svyatoslav. Looking through your answer, it seems that this would be the way to go. Some computed fields would be lightweight enough to store in the model whereas others would consume too much memory so I need to really decide on one method and stick with it. I know this is subjective but where would you store the custom models / helpers in this scenario? ViewModels / Helpers? Or would you stick to the base class?

Comment: I have been paying with Nein Linq and it looks to be a great solution. Only issue is, if you create a model such as CustomerWithBalance then the returned json is not correct. You would have your customer object and then Balance would be outside the customer container. How to tackle that?

Comment: Where to place that... I prefer extensions and namespace Extensions. I have created sample VieewModel and usually for each request you have your own ViewModel and how to build it really depends,

Comment: Makes perfect sense. This has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer to calculate at property level. Add an `InvoiceBal` readonly field to the `SalesInvoice` model.

```
public class SalesInvoice 
{ 
   public double InvoiceBal => SalesInvoiceDetails.Sum(x => x.Qty * x.UnitPrice)
   public virtual IEnumerable<SalesInvoiceDetail> SalesInvoiceDetails{ get; set; } 
}
```

Add another `TotalBalance` readonly field to the `Customer` that sums the whole thing

```
public class Customer 
{
   public double TotalBal => SalesInvoices.Sum(x => x.InvoiceBal)
   public virtual IEnumerable<SalesInvoice> SalesInvoices{ get; set; } 
}
```